# Amazon S3 access for other AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to give access permission for S3 bucket in account to another account.

For the created bucket in permission tab there is an option of Access for other AWS accounts. Under that I am seeing an Add Account button. I clicked it and gave my other account from which I want to access this bucket.

However, I am getting an `Invalid ID` error.

Answer (score 8):

If you wish to grant access to specific **User** in a different account, it's quite simple. (I don't think this method will work for giving access to a different **Account**.)

Let's say you have:

- Account A with **Bucket A** that you own
- Account B with **User B** to which you wish to grant access

Ask User B for the **ARN** associated with their IAM User. This can be seen in the IAM Management Console and it will look like:

```
arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/fred
```

Then, add a **Bucket Policy** to Bucket A:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "S3AccessPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "GiveFredAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/fred"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This will allow Fred to access the S3 bucket. This works for users in the *same* account AND for users in a *different* account.

Comment: this is not relevant (although it can be correct action in a different scenario)

Answer (score 5):

For getting the canonical ID, one of the simplest ways is to use CLI and run 
`aws s3api list-buckets` command. 
You will get the ID in the output.

There are other ways also for getting the canonical ID and are clearly described in the aws docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html

list-buckets aws docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-buckets.html

Answer (score 3):

You need the "canonical user id". You can find out about this [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html#FindingCanonicalId).

> To view your canonical user ID as a root user (console)
>
> Sign in as the root user using your AWS account email address and password.
>
> ... snip ...
>
> In the top right of the console, choose your account name or number. Then choose My Security Credentials.
>
> If necessary, in the dialog box, choose Continue to Security Credentials. You can choose the box next to Don’t show me this message again to stop the dialog box from appearing in the future.
>
> Expand the Account Identifiers section to view your canonical user ID.
>
> Note
>   If you do not see the Account Identifiers section, then you are not signed in as the root user. Return to Step 1 above. If you do not have access to the root user credentials, contact your AWS account administrator and ask them to retrieve the canonical user ID.

Comment: This doesn't work if you're trying to set permissions for a different user (not the root user).

Comment: Short answer is you can do it, but both the resource owner and the parent account for the user need to grant permissions. Have a look at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html

Comment: @Chris PS also if you down voted, please remember that the context of the OPs question was about a specific scenario in the UI that requires canonical user id's, not a generic cross account access question.